# Smallest natural number non-divisible by 4, has 12 divisors, whose square has 45 divisors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I have been tasked with finding the smallest natural number $n$ not divisible by 4, where the number of divisors of $n$ is 12, and where the number of divisors of $n^2$ is 45.

So far I've been able to find that the number formed by the last two digits can't be divisible by 4. Other than that, I don't know how to proceed. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** A straightforward counting argument shows that the number of divisors of a natural number $n$ with prime factorization $$n = p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_k^{a_k}$$ is $$(a_1 + 1) \cdots (a_k + 1) .$$ So, for example, the condition that $n$ has exactly $12$ divisors is just $$(a_1 + 1) \cdots (a_k + 1) = 12 .$$
Now, what is the condition that the square $n^2$ has $45$ factors, in terms of $a_1, \ldots, a_k$?

> **Additional hint** To find the condition on $a_1, \ldots, a_k$ so that $n^2$ has $45$ factors, first determine how to write the prime factorization of $n^2$ in terms of $a_1, \ldots, a_k$.)

Comment: hmm could you provide info how to perform the prime factorization of $n^2$? I'm new to discrete mathematics so it's kind of hard! Thanks!

Comment: **Hint** If $n = p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_k^{a_k}$, then $n^2 = (p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_k^{a_k})^2$, but we can rewrite the right-hand side of that second equation as a product of powers of distinct primes, which in turn must be the prime factorization of $n^2$.

Comment: @TravisWillse what I did was end up with an equation: $(2a_1 + 1)(2a_2+1)...(2a_k+1)=45$. I'm not sure if it's correct and how to proceed.

Comment: @l0ner9 That looks correct to me! Now, we're looking for numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_k$ that satisfy both our equations in those values. Since $a_i + 1 \geq 2$ for all $a_i$, there are only finitely many solutions $(a_1, \ldots, a_k)$ to $(a_1 + 1) \cdots (a_k + 1) = 12$. Which of those are also solutions of the equation you derived from the prime factorization of the square, $n^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be any number of the form $p^2qr$, where $p,q,$ and $r$ are distinct primes. Then, $n$ has exactly $(2+1)(1+1)(1+1)=(3)(2)(2)=12$ divisors, while $n^2$ has exactly $(4+1)(2+1)(2+1)=(5)(3)(3)=45$ divisors.

If $p=2$, then $n$ is divisible by $4$, so $p$ must be an odd prime. Letting $p=3, q=2,$ and $r=5$, $p^2qr=(9)(2)(5)=90$ is the smallest solution.